# Java Instantiating an object from a class type

Tags: java

I happened upon a seemingly simple problem that I have trouble figuring out. My goal is to create a spawner object that creates an object whenever it is called, something like this:

```
public class FishSpawner{
   public Fish spawnFish(){
      return new BlueFish(0, 0);
   }
}
```

This works and lets me create blue fish at the 0,0 coordinates of my world. But instead of copying this class for each type of Fish I want to spawn I figured i save the type of fish I want to spawn in the constructor and then create an object of that class in the spawn function.
Like this:

```
public class FishSpawner{

private Class<? extends Fish> fishType;

public FishSpawner(Class<? extends Fish> fishType){
   this.fishType = fishType;
}

   public Fish spawnFish(){
      return fishType.newInstance(0, 0);
   }
}
```

However this does not work. It tells me that newInstance is deprecated and it also won't allow me to pass arguments to its constructor. But all the examples I've managed to google up use the newInstance method. Could anybody here point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use Constructor#newInstance instead - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: `fishType.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, int.class).newInstance(0,0)`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, OP explicitly wants to invoke a parameterized constructor. Your code is not able to do that. My link explains how OP could accomplish it. (Oh, and the code after your edit shouldn't even work.)

Comment: BTW, what you call a "Spawner" is essentially a "Factory" in standard Java parlance.

Comment: @Taschi I had a bad connection so I ended up editing it 5 times :D

Comment: @AniketSahrawat and I'm on train wifi on a machine with no jshell. `int.class` still seems like it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Taschi It behaves correctly.

Comment: Much cleaner, use `Supplier<T extends Fish>`. You can even pass it the method handle `BlueFish::new`.

Comment: @Taschi — I use reflection a lot ... `int.class` works just fine. It is the [documented way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) to use for primitives; the javadoc uses byte as an example: `byte.class.getName()` — this works fine: `Constructor<? extends TestClass> ctor = TestClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, int.class);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing the following

```
public <T extends Fish> spawnFish(){
      Constructor<T> constructor = fishType.getConstructor(Integer.class, Integer.class);
      return constructor.newInstance(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I fear that won't compile because of the two `Integer`.

Comment: My bad, I overlooked that detail by writing code on the fly, I corrected it, Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! So in essence I need to get a specific constructor based on the arguments it takes and call newInstance on that, instead of calling newInstance directly.